# How to update the image in the image button at refreshing the page in android?

Tags: android, user-interface

Is any possibility to update the IMAGE in the ImageButton or ImageView at the time of refreshing the page in Android.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

i'm not sure, i understood your question right, but you can use in Application's onResume method setImageResource, setImageDrawable or setImageBitmap

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this-

```
 @Override
        protected void onResume() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Bitmap image = (Bitmap)intnt.getParcelableExtra(R.drawable.image1);
    ImageView imgview = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
            imgview.setImageBitmap(image);`enter code here`
                
        }
```